# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta condicionada si el elemento está más veces en una tabla que en otra?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las tablas `elemento` con una PK e `ingresa` y `retira` con la FK proveniente de elemento, en donde el elemento puede estar varias veces en cada tabla de `ingresa` y `retira`.

Lo que quiero es hacer una consulta que me muestre los elementos cuando la cuenta del elemento en la tabla `ingresa` sea menor que la cuenta de ese mismo elemento en la tabla `retira`.

Hasta el momento voy así pero no logro unir los diferentes `select` de forma correcta:

```
SELECT e_id 
FROM elemento 
WHERE (SELECT count(e_id) from ingresa) > (SELECT count(e_id) from retira)
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿No convendría mejor resolver esto con programación auxiliándose del lenguaje de backend que uses?

Comment: Utilizare PHP para el backend pero por el momento estamos creando solo las consultas, creo que es posible hacer lo que quiero desde la propia consulta, pero no logro ubicar bien las condiciones

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo basado en datos con los resultados que esperas? No queda claro lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Debes agrupar primero en dos subconsultas la cantidad por cada elemento y luego los comparas, si necesitas datos de otras tablas los unes nada mas.

```
select I.e_id from 
(select e_id, count(*) cantidad from ingresa group by e_id) I 
join (select e_id, count(*) cantidad from retira group by e_id) R
    on I.e_id = R.e_id
where I.cantidad > R.cantidad
```